# "source is not IEnumerable<>" error when using SqlQuery(Type,string,object[]).AsQueryable()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, reflection

Here is the problem

i am executing raw sql queries in controller as

```
var ctx=new DBModel();

public ActionResult Grid(string tbname,string query,object args)
{
   var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("Demo.Models." + tbname));
   dynamic queryresult;
   queryresult=ctx.Database.SqlQuery(obj.GetType(),query,args).AsQueryable();
}
```

I am getting the result of query in queryresult when i am using

```
queryresult=ctx.Database.SqlQuery(obj.GetType(),query,args);
```

but when when i am applying AsQueryable to it for operations like Count i am getting the error as

source is not IEnumerable<>

Please Help to solve this

Comment: what is return type of ctx.Database.SqlQuery(obj.GetType(),query,args)

Comment: query is general select statement say select * from DemoTable

Comment: return type is IEnumerable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of converting queryresult to `IQueryable`, make it generic :

```
queryresult = ctx.Database.SqlQuery(obj.GetType(),query,args).Cast<object>();
var count = queryresult.Count();
```

`IEnumerable<T>` (in your case `IEnumerable<object>`, as you don't know which type at compile time) will allow you to perform many operations.

Comment: It worked...:) in addition to your code, i just changed dynamic queryresult to IEnumerable queryresult and for getting count var count=queryresult.AsQueryable.Count();